# Why are Chrome and Safari for Ipad 2 messing up my CSS triangles?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am trying to create a banner effect using just CSS and no images. The result is supposed to look like this:

[image]

This example was created using the html and CSS in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDyTc/). This is the CSS for the banner (`.widget-title`):

```
.widget-title
{
    background-color: #B1DDC9;
    color: white;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

.widget-title:before
{
    content: "";
    float:left;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 0px 12px 12px;
    border-color: #B1DDC9 #B1DDC9 #B1DDC9 white;
}

.widget-title:after
{
    content: "";
    float:right;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 12px 12px 0px;
    border-color: #B1DDC9 white #B1DDC9 white;
}
```

This seems to work fine on all the browsers I've tested on my desktop and phone. Both Safari and Chrome on my Ipad2 however render a faint thin line on the left and right outer edges of the banner:

[image]

What is causing this phenomenon? Is there anything I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Try wiping the screen of your Ipad

Comment: Just FYI, when using iOS, all browsers are rendering with Safari...including Chrome. All the iOS web browsers use a built-in WebKit engine to draw.

Comment: Try to change white into transparent in border-color of .widget-title:before and .widget-title:after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it is the background colour bleeding through at the edge of the triangle, probably due to some kind of sub-pixel rendering quirk. From your CSS this shouldn't be happening, as the triangles should be butted up against the edges of the title, but that's CSS for you ;)

Not sure if it'll work for you, but you could try putting `position:relative` on the title and `position:absolute` on the two triangles, with the relevant `left:0` and `right:0` to position the where you want them. In my experience this is generally more reliable than floating in terms of where your elements will end up.

As a side note, you could use `border-color:transparent` for the three sides you don't want to display. This would also allow you to make the triangle one pixel bigger and overlap the left/right by a pixel (i.e. `left:-1px`). That should definitely sort your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `border-width: 12px 0px 12px 12px;`
to `border-width: 12px 2px 12px 12px;`

Maybe this will extend the "back" of the triangle just off the banner and get rid of the line